# Proguard fails to read android.jar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

I just enable Proguard ( minifyEnabled true ) ... and when I try to build singed apk I get error :

> Cause: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x9aa3fedc but got 0xfeb7201b)
>
> Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\AndroidStudio\AndroidStudioSDK\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar] (invalid entry CRC (expected 0x9aa3fedc but got 0xfeb7201b))

my Gradle.app is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "*****-****-****-****-***********",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_URL', serverUrl
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //ANDROID API
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //Google API
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:16.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
    //Google Exo Player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.9.4'
    //Google Firebase Api
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    //Other Libraries
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.ornolfr:rating-view:0.1.2@aar'
    implementation 'cn.gavinliu.android.lib:ShapedImageView:0.8.4'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ixiDev:GDPRChecker:v0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.halilozercan:BetterVideoPlayer:1.1.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    //OneSignal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1@aar'
    //You Api
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    //Test Api
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So I don't change anything just **minifyEnabled** from false to true and I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invalid entry CRC (expected 0x9aa3fedc but got 0xfeb7201b)` means the file is corrupted.

you'd have to uninstall and reinstall API level 27 with the SDK manager, to get around that.

and probably consider getting a new drive - or at least check the integrity eg. with [hddscan](http://hddscan.com).

Comment: It works, the problem was uninstall and reinstall API level 27 with the SDK manager, now it works.